# Input Reset to value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Goal**

I'm trying to create a button that Onclick resets each individuals values to the Original value of each individual input value.

I've setup a Codepen example here: 
http://codepen.io/coryk/pen/QEGrXp

**Problem**

When the user clicks the reset button it does reset, but it resets to the firsts inputs value and I need it to reset it to each individual value.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
   <tr>
      <td>Max Pumping Distance</td>
    <td>
        <input name="custom_coverage" class="input_green custom_coverage" id="max-pumping" type="number" value="44000">
    </td>
    <td>ft</td>
</tr>

<br/>
<tr>
    <td>Avg. Pumping Distance</td>
    <td>
        <input name="custom_coverage"  class="input_green custom_coverage"  id="avg-pumping-distance" type="number" value="30000">
    </td>
    <td>ft</td>
</tr>

<br/>
<tr>
    <td>Head Pressure</td>
    <td>
        <input name="custom_coverage"  class="input_green custom_coverage"  id="avg-pumping-distance" type="number" value="45000">
    </td>
    <td>ft</td>
</tr>
<br/>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

JavaScript

```
//Reset to Default Input values 
var $input = $('.custom_coverage'),
    $reset = $('#reset')
$('#reset').data('default', $input.val() );

$reset.on('click', function() {
   $input.val($(this).data('default')); 
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for `<button type="reset">..`?

Comment: Will that reset each inputs value Onclick?

Comment: That will reset the entire `form` to its initial state.

Comment: Is your jQuery in a document ready handler or at the end of the page?

Comment: Could you edit the Codepen example to show how that would work perhaps?

Comment: Is this what you looking for?? https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zzsxsnzy/

Comment: @j08691 No, it's nether the JQuery is sitting on my Javascript file.

Comment: 1: The variable `$input` would contain all the input elements, calling `.val()` on that would give you the value of the first element in there. You could start with correcting that.
2: As @Quantastical suggested you could use a `<input type="reset" />` while enclosing all the input elements to reset in a single `form` tag.

Comment: @NikhilGirraj Great advise Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first assign a new attribute to each input field and store the original value there, then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
     $('.custom_coverage').each(function () {
        var orgValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
      $(this).val(orgValue);
     });
  });
});
```

See my jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/gusff8ep/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set each input individually:

```
$reset.on('click', function() {
  $input.each(function(i) {
    $(i).val($(i).data('default'));
  }); 
});
```

```